# RabbitMQ could not create a exchange，Erlang error {:undef, [{:rabbit_exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

**RabbitMQ 3.8.17 / Erlang 24.0.2 / Mac Pro Big Sur**

**My command**
rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_exchange:declare({resource, <<"vhost1">>, exchange, <<"exchange_test">>}, topic, true, false, false, []).'

**Error message：**
Error:
{:undef, [{:rabbit_exchange, :declare, [{:resource, "vhost1", :exchange, "exchange_test"}, :topic, true, false, false, []], []}, {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 685]}, {:erl_eval, :exprs, 2, []}]}

Could you please tell me what error this could be？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not use the internals to interact with RabbitMQ.
There are several ready [clients to do that](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html)

This is the right command to use btw:

```
rabbitmqctl eval 'rabbit_exchange:declare({resource,<<"/">>,exchange,<<"myexchange">>}, fanout, false, false, false, [],<<"rmqinternal">>).'
```